# Sql query in DAO class regarding

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I converted date datatype  to string and stored in table as a string.I want to write a query to show results between certain date.I wrote like this

```
 public Statement getstatement(Statement s) throws SQLException {
        long accid=0;
        Statement s1=null;
        Connection conn=DatabaseUtil.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement psmt=conn.prepareStatement("select * from Account_groupc_tja05 where Account_id =?");
        psmt.setLong(1,s.getAccid());
        System.out.println("inside dao");
        ResultSet rs=psmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
             accid=rs.getLong(1);
             System.out.println("inside while");
        }
        if(s.getAccid()==accid){
            System.out.println("inside if");
            PreparedStatement psmt1=conn.prepareStatement("select * from deposit1_groupc_tja05 where Account_id =? and Transaction_Date between ? and ?");
            psmt1.setLong(1, accid);
            psmt1.setString(2, s.getDatefrom());
            psmt1.setString(3, s.getDateto());
            System.out.println(s.getDateto());
            ResultSet rs1=psmt1.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next()){
                System.out.println("inside inner while");
                 s1=new Statement(rs.getString(6),rs.getLong(7),rs.getLong(4),rs.getLong(3),rs.getString(5));
                 System.out.println(s1);
            }
        }

        return s1;
    }
```

But this query is not executing. Why?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and what "not executing means."

Comment: Well, are you actually executing it?

Comment: The Java you posted is clearly wrong; there's no "prepare statement" in Java.  There is a "prepareStatement".  Why represent dates as strings?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, there is nothing like `Prepared statement` and you'd want to `execute` the `ps` to "execute the query".  e.g.

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("Select * from deposit where transaction_date between ? And ?");
ps.setString(1,fromdate);
ps.setString(2,todate);
ps.execute();
ps.close();
```

Also you need to enter your database credentials in your connection statement

```
Connection conn=DatabaseUtil.getConnection();
```

to

```
Connection conn=DatabaseUtil.getConnection(<databaseurl>, <username>, <password>);
```

Comment: @Pravin Did you try this?

Comment: you are not making connection to database

Comment: what database are you using?-  mysql, mssql?

Comment: I already did the connection.But how can I assign values for between in query

Comment: You are not connecting to database, there is no method in the snippet which authenticates to database.